# how to check number of times a dynamoDB table has been accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a dynamoDB table lets say sampleTable. I want to find out how many times this table has been accessed from cli. How do i check this?

PS. I have checked the metrics but couldnt find any particular metric which gives this information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CloudWatch metric to monitor API calls to DynamoDB.

However, there is [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) (CT). Thus you can to go CT's **event history** and look for API calls to DynamoDB from the last **90 days**. You can export the history to a CSV file, and investigate off line as well.

For **ongoing monitoring** of the API calls you can enable CT trail which will store event log details in S3 for as long as you require:

- [Logging DynamoDB Operations by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)

If you have the trial created, you can use `Amazon Athena` to **query the log data** for the statistics of interests, such as number of specific API calls to DynamoDb:

- [Querying AWS CloudTrail Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html)

Also, you could create **custom metric** based on the trial's log data (once you configure CloudWatch logs for the trial):

- [Analyzing AWS CloudTrail in Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/analyzing-cloudtrail-in-cloudwatch/)

However, I don't think you can differentiate between API calls done using CLI, or SDK or by other means.